# Remove white screen that comes before opening custom camera in swift 4

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, swift4

I am trying to add custom camera functionality in my app following this tutorial.[Appcoda custom camera](https://www.appcoda.com/avfoundation-swift-guide/)

I am able to achieve all the functionailties of camera like taking photo,flash and switch camera but before the camera comes,white screen comes for a second.I want the camera to open directly .Kindly give some suggestion that how can I get the camera functionality directly without getting any white screen.

Answer (score 0):

That white screen in actually Launch Screen, which comes by default, if you wish to change that you may go to LaunchScreen.storyboard and change UI there.

You can also remove LaunchScreen property in info.plist file, which is **not advisable** but that'll just display black screen instead of while while launching the App.

Comment: On launchscreen ,I have already added a image on imageview...but still that gets me white screen before opening custom camera.

Comment: Does that image on LaunchScreen ever shows? Also check your info.plist file
"Launch screen interface file base name" should be set to "LaunchScreen".

Comment: Ya,that image comes as splashscreen